# socket.io-redis-adapter - issue with fetchSocket()

Tags: sockets, socket.io, publish-subscribe, node-redis

i am using pm2 cluster mode for my node app and when i try to fetch socket via

```
// return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the main namespace
const sockets = await io.in("room1").fetchSockets();
```

sometimes i got actual socket where i have append some custom data eventMetaData and sometimes i got remote socket which doesn’t have my custom data, please find below the actual socket and remote socket that i get

````
1|test-app  | sockets--- [
    1|test-app  |   Socket {
    1|test-app  |     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    1|test-app  |       error: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    1|test-app  |       req: [Function: bound requestHandler] AsyncFunction,
    1|test-app  |       disconnect: [Function (anonymous)]
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     _eventsCount: 3,
    1|test-app  |     _maxListeners: undefined,
    1|test-app  |     nsp: Namespace {
    1|test-app  |       _events: [Object: null prototype],
    1|test-app  |       _eventsCount: 1,
    1|test-app  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
    1|test-app  |       sockets: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       _fns: [],
    1|test-app  |       _ids: 0,
    1|test-app  |       server: [Server],
    1|test-app  |       name: '/',
    1|test-app  |       adapter: [RedisAdapter],
    1|test-app  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     client: Client {
    1|test-app  |       sockets: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       nsps: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       server: [Server],
    1|test-app  |       conn: [Socket],
    1|test-app  |       encoder: Encoder {},
    1|test-app  |       decoder: [Decoder],
    1|test-app  |       id: 'pIQW8CCYn82_GSpoAAAP',
    1|test-app  |       onclose: [Function: bound onclose],
    1|test-app  |       ondata: [Function: bound ondata],
    1|test-app  |       onerror: [Function: bound onerror],
    1|test-app  |       ondecoded: [Function: bound ondecoded],
    1|test-app  |       connectTimeout: undefined
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     data: {},
    1|test-app  |     acks: Map(0) {},
    1|test-app  |     fns: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
    1|test-app  |     flags: {},
    1|test-app  |     server: Server {
    1|test-app  |       _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    1|test-app  |       _eventsCount: 0,
    1|test-app  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
    1|test-app  |       _nsps: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       parentNsps: Map(0) {},
    1|test-app  |       _path: '/socket.io',
    1|test-app  |       clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
    1|test-app  |       _connectTimeout: 45000,
    1|test-app  |       _serveClient: true,
    1|test-app  |       _parser: [Object],
    1|test-app  |       encoder: Encoder {},
    1|test-app  |       _adapter: [Function (anonymous)],
    1|test-app  |       sockets: [Namespace],
    1|test-app  |       opts: [Object],
    1|test-app  |       eio: [Server],
    1|test-app  |       httpServer: [Server],
    1|test-app  |       engine: [Server],
    1|test-app  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     adapter: RedisAdapter {
    1|test-app  |       _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    1|test-app  |       _eventsCount: 0,
    1|test-app  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
    1|test-app  |       nsp: [Namespace],
    1|test-app  |       rooms: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       sids: [Map],
    1|test-app  |       encoder: Encoder {},
    1|test-app  |       pubClient: [RedisClient],
    1|test-app  |       subClient: [RedisClient],
    1|test-app  |       requests: Map(0) {},
    1|test-app  |       uid: 'dh0K01',
    1|test-app  |       requestsTimeout: 5000,
    1|test-app  |       publishOnSpecificResponseChannel: false,
    1|test-app  |       channel: 'socket.io#/#',
    1|test-app  |       requestChannel: 'socket.io-request#/#',
    1|test-app  |       responseChannel: 'socket.io-response#/#',
    1|test-app  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     id: 'pIQW8CCYn82_GSpoAAAP',
    1|test-app  |     connected: true,
    1|test-app  |     disconnected: false,
    1|test-app  |     handshake: {
    1|test-app  |       headers: [Object],
    1|test-app  |       time: 'Fri Jul 08 2022 05:48:10 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)',
    1|test-app  |       address: '::ffff:10.30.11.223',
    1|test-app  |       xdomain: false,
    1|test-app  |       secure: false,
    1|test-app  |       issued: 1657259290376,
    1|test-app  |       url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
    1|test-app  |       query: [Object: null prototype],
    1|test-app  |       auth: {}
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     eventMetaData: {
    1|test-app  |       userObjectId: '12345',
    1|test-app  |     },
    1|test-app  |     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    1|test-app  |   }
    1|test-app  | ]
    ```

and remote socket sometimes

    2|test-app  | sockets--- [
        2|test-app  |   RemoteSocket {
        2|test-app  |     id: 'XCqoMchtLYdsB9ldAAAJ',
        2|test-app  |     handshake: {
        2|test-app  |       headers: [Object],
        2|test-app  |       time: 'Fri Jul 08 2022 06:10:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)',
        2|test-app  |       address: '::ffff:10.30.1.185',
        2|test-app  |       xdomain: false,
        2|test-app  |       secure: false,
        2|test-app  |       issued: 1657260613462,
        2|test-app  |       url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
        2|test-app  |       query: [Object],
        2|test-app  |       auth: {}
        2|test-app  |     },
        2|test-app  |     rooms: Set(2) {
        2|test-app  |       'XCqoMchtLYdsB9ldAAAJ',
        2|test-app  |       'ef88ce1b91524264bbb020bcafe6b61c'
        2|test-app  |     },
        2|test-app  |     data: {},
        2|test-app  |     operator: BroadcastOperator {
        2|test-app  |       adapter: [RedisAdapter],
        2|test-app  |       rooms: [Set],
        2|test-app  |       exceptRooms: Set(0) {},
        2|test-app  |       flags: {}
        2|test-app  |     }
        2|test-app  |   }
        2|test-app  | ]
````

with

```
socketClient.sockets.sockets.get(socketId)
```

i'm getting null incase of RemoteSocket, when actual socket is not returned
how can i get my actual socket every time in pm2 cluster..??? and what is the difference between the term Socket and Remote Socket (see 1st element of sockets array)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting your eventMetaData object within the socket data object, e.g.:

```
socket.data.eventMetaData = {userObjectId: '12345'}
```

You can then access the data again using:

```
// Get the sockets from server server cluster
const sockets = await io.in("room1").fetchSockets();

// Find the socket you want in the room (and check sockets isn't zero length)
if (sockets && sockets.length > 0) {
    // Going to assume you want the first socket in the room
    const socket = sockets[0];
    const metadata = socket.data.eventMetaData;
}
else {
    // Didn't get any sockets for the room - handle that
}
```

Described here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchsockets